# How to fix apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable misbehaving on emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing an application that uses google maps and I encountered a weird problem when trying to launch my app on emulator - it (obviously) doesn't work and shows an error message "MyApp having trouble with Google Play services. Please try again".

To solve this problem, I decided to check the availability of Google Play Services (as recommended in this guide by Google https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). And.. it doesn't work as intended.

So, here's the code I use to check the availability of Google Play Services and the result code for the emulator is always SUCCESS, even though it doesn't have the desired version installed.

```
 private fun checkPlayServices(): Boolean {
        val apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
        val resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity)
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this.activity, resultCode, 9000)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Timber.tag("tag").e("This device is not supported.")
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

In logs I can clearly see the message

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 13400000 but found 13280022

And I cannot comprehend why Google says that there are google play services installed on a version without google play service

I expected this function to return some kind of error and show the correct dialog, but it just returns success for the emulator. 
Though, if I run it on a version WITHOUT google API, it shows the error correctly about not having google play services completely.

So, my question is - is it a problem with emulator or API and will it misbehave like this on normal phones or this is just an emulator bug (feature)?

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?